# What is the R equivalent for Excel IFERROR?

Tags: r, excel, error-handling, try-catch

I am trying to put IFERROR condition in R like Excel IFERROR Function. I am building a random forest model. To fine tune, i use tuneRF function. It helps to give optimal mtry parameter.

```
#Selecting Optimal MTRY parameter
mtry <- tuneRF(dat3[, -36], dat3[,36], ntreeTry=1000, stepFactor=1.5,improve=0.01, trace=TRUE, plot=TRUE)
best.m <- mtry[mtry[, 2] == min(mtry[, 2]), 1]
```

**SOMETIMES, the above function returns error if OOB error would not improve in different iterations.**

**Error in if (Improve > improve) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE 
needed.**

Next Step : If the above function works fine, i use the value of best.m in the code below.

**No ERROR in tuneRF function - Run the code below.**

```
rf <-randomForest(classe~.,data=dat3, mtry=best.m, importance=TRUE,ntree=1000)
```

**ERROR in tuneRF function - Run the code below.**

```
#Train Random Forest
rf <-randomForest(classe~.,data=dat3, importance=TRUE,ntree=1000)
```

Thanks in anticipation! Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't get the question, the format you need to follow is: what do I want, what do I get, here's a dput of my data, and here's my code, help!

Comment: I have edited my question. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: [Using R — Basic error Handing with `tryCatch()`](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `try` or `tryCatch`. This should work:

```
mtry <- try(tuneRF(dat3[, -36], dat3[,36], ntreeTry=1000,
  stepFactor=1.5,improve=0.01, trace=TRUE, plot=TRUE))
if (!inherits(mtry, "try-error")) {
  best.m <- mtry[mtry[, 2] == min(mtry[, 2]), 1]
  rf <- randomForest(classe~.,data=dat3, mtry=best.m, importance=TRUE,ntree=1000)
} else {
  rf <- randomForest(classe~.,data=dat3, importance=TRUE,ntree=1000)
}
```

However, the error given may represent a bug in the `tuneRF` function. Can you give a reproducible example, i.e. with a minimal dataset that will produce the error?

Comment: Thanks a ton! I wish i could paste my data here. This error comes rarely so making such dataset that produces this error is very difficult

Answer (score 1):

## The R equivalent to Excel's ifERROR function

```
try2 <- function(code, silent = FALSE) {
  tryCatch(code, error = function(c) {
    if (!silent) {"Error Message"}
    else{code}})}
```