# Issue using try within R to catch errors with importing files

Tags: r, try-catch

I have a process in R in which I am importing a number of files in R.

Occasionally there are issues with some of the files, for example there isn't an EOF character present in the file that I'm reading in, so the read.table statement errors.

As there are a lot of files to process this is difficult to manage manually, so I would like to use some error trapping to alter the user of the issue and carry on with the other files.

I have tried using `try` and referenced the SOF post [What is the R equivalent for Excel IFERROR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214361/what-is-the-r-equivalent-for-excel-iferror)

Below I would like to test the import then depending on the result either give some message to the user or actually import the file.

```
  mtry <- try(read.table("~/file_location/test_file.csv", 
                        fill = TRUE,
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE))


  if (!inherits(mtry, "try-error")) {

    read.table("~/file_location/test_file..csv", 
               fill = TRUE,
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  } else {

    message("File doesn't exist, please check")

  }
```

The issue is that the `try()` statement is producing an error in the log which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: For the scenario you described you could also check out `?file.exists` which returns a logical that you could conveniently use in your if else statement

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you give an example here as I'm not sure how it applies - because the file exists its just erroring because there is no eof character present

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try suppressing the report of error messages by specifying `try(..., silent = TRUE`) (see also `?try`). I tested the code below with a non-existing dummy file, used `if (class(mtry) != "try-error")` and it works fine.

```
some_dummy_file <- "data/dummy.csv"

mtry <- try(read.table(some_dummy_file, sep = ",", header = TRUE), 
            silent = TRUE)

if (class(mtry) != "try-error") {
  read.table(some_dummy_file, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
} else {
  message("File doesn't exist, please check")
}
```

And here is the console output.

```
> File doesn't exist, please check
```

Comment: Just for the record, you might want to re-write your code a little bit since `read.table` is duplicated. This means that if the file inside your `try` statement exists, it is currently saved to 'mtry', but subsequently re-imported inside the if-else clause.